# Can not open a CUDA project in the CLion IDE

Tags: cuda, clion, jetbrains-ide

I recently started learning CUDA with the new CLion 2020 release. I am on a Windows machine using CUDA 11.0 and CLion 2020.2 EAP (Same happens on the stable 2020.1.2 as well)

Upon opening a new project from the project wizard, I get this error from CMake:

```
-- The CUDA compiler identification is unknown
-- Detecting CUDA compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CUDA compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.0/bin/nvcc.exe
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.0/bin/nvcc.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/CMakeTestCUDACompiler.cmake:52 (message):
  The CUDA compiler

    "C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.0/bin/nvcc.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Users/AregevDev/Desktop/CudaTest/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command(s):nmake /nologo cmTC_56b95\fast &&   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"  -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_56b95.dir\build.make /nologo -L                  CMakeFiles\cmTC_56b95.dir\build
    Building CUDA object CMakeFiles/cmTC_56b95.dir/main.cu.obj
        C:\PROGRA~1\NVIDIA~2\CUDA\v11.0\bin\nvcc.exe      -c C:\Users\AregevDev\Desktop\CudaTest\cmake-build-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\main.cu -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_56b95.dir\main.cu.obj
    nvcc fatal   : Could not set up the environment for Microsoft Visual Studio using 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/HostX64/x64/../../../../../../../VC/Auxiliary/Build/vcvars64.bat'
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\PROGRA~1\NVIDIA~2\CUDA\v11.0\bin\nvcc.exe' : return code '0x1'
    Stop.
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
    Stop.
    
    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/AregevDev/Desktop/CudaTest/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/AregevDev/Desktop/CudaTest/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I have `cl.exe` in the `PATH`. When running it from the VS developer prompt, it does work.
My settings page look like this:
[image]

I have no idea what's wrong with it, perhaps the CUDA support is broken

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the CMake that is bundled with CLion. you are currently using a cmake version that is not supported. click on the CMake option and you will be able to see the CMake that is listed as "bundled".